# Find most recently used Eclipse editor of specific type

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

In Eclipse it's possible to have a range of Editor types open.

It's possible to retrieve the active editor, or a list of all open editors.

But, I wish to retrieve the most recently accessed editor of a particular type.

An example of this would be where a Java developer has a number of Java editors open, and a number of POM editors open.  Is there a way of retrieving the most recently accessed POM editor, even if it's not the active one?[image]

Comment: No, Eclipse doesn't remember access order.

Comment: In your screenshot, if in _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance_ the check box _Show most recently used tabs_ is checked, it must be either `info.limpet/pom.xml` or `org.geotools/pom.xml` but not one of the four hidden editors (= if in Ctrl+E there are some displayed in bold and some not in bold, it must be one of the non-bold; if all are in bold, it is the topmost). That's all that's built in. Maybe there is an editor history plug-in for that.